# Determining if a limit of a infinite series exists

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, bounded-variation

Let $f: (0,\infty) \to (0,\infty)$ be a continuous, decreasing, non-negative function.

I am trying to prove that a certain expression including this function has a limit.

Lets say I wanted to prove that the limit,

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n f(k)   $$

exists.

I think I want to use the *Monotone Convergence Theorem* to prove that the series converges, but for that I have to show that the sequence is bounded and here is were I get stuck.

Does the sum from 1 to infinity somehow make the infinite series bounded? (since it is decreasing?)

Is there another technique to make it bounded or am I looking at this problem from the wrong perspective?

I feel that I am a bit in over my head with this question, so any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By taking $f(x):=\frac 1x$ one sees that your conditions on $f$ do *not* ensure convergence of the given series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by *the limit exists*.

If you mean by that that you want it to be real, it is false, take

$$f(x)=1/x.$$

If you want the limit to be in $[0,+\infty]$, it exists since

$$\left(\sum_{k=0}^nf(k)\right)_n$$

is an increasing ($f$ is positive) positive sequence, so it must converges in $[0,+\infty]$.

Comment: But then, the assumption that $f$ be non-decreasing is unnecessary.

Comment: @ClementC. Yes, and we also don't need it to be continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ assumes only non-negative values, the sequence $\sum_{k=1}^nf(k)$ is non-decreasing, therefore it has a limit in $[0,\infty]$.

Comment: But then, the assumption that $f$ be non-decreasing is unnecessary.

Comment: @ClementC. Yes indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Under your assumptions, the limit (that always exists, finite or $+\infty$) is finite if and only if the improper integral
$$
\int_1^{+\infty} f(x)\, dx
$$
is convergent.
(This is the [integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) for convergence of a series.)

Comment: Can we, from the information given above, draw any conclusion about if the improper integral is convergent? Or can we only know this if one or the other is convergent?

Comment: From the information above you cannot conclude. For example, if $f(x) = x^{-\alpha}$, then the series (and the improper integral) are convergent if and only if $\alpha > 1$.